# Does google-api-services-translate and google-cloud-translate do the same thing?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-cloud-vision

Android Dev with [cloud translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)

I see that they are all libraries of the translator. The cloud-vision has two libraries as well but in the Android [Sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/blob/master/android/README.md) we use the [cloud-vision of google-api-services](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-vision) different from [cloud-service](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-vision). Does the translator-API do the same like vision-api?

Latest versions of libraries:

google-api-services-translate: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-translate/v2-rev49-1.22.0

google-cloud-translate:https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-translate/0.18.0-beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and interpret your question, but it's not exactly clear what you are asking,

The previous/old libraries are auto-generated. Some of them are not very intuitive to work with, hard to test, and require you to write lots of boilerplate code.

So, Google started rolling out newer libraries to improve the experience. Some are now hand written, more idiomatic, and some benefit from gRPC. In fact, you'll actually find that the newer libraries simply sit on top of the older ones. For example, here is a snippet of the dependancy tree for the [BigQuery client library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery):

```
+--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:0.8.1-beta
|    +--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:0.8.1-alpha
|    |    +--- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:0.6.0
|    |    +--- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.6.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:0.6.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0 -> 1.22.0
[..]
|    \--- com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev330-1.22.0
|         \--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0 (*)
[..]
```

In short, you should use the newer *"Google Cloud Client Libraries"*. For example these [Cloud Vision](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-vision) and [Cloud Translate](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-translate) ones.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) is a page with more details.

Comment: one line to my question is different between the client library of 
google-api-services-translate and the client library of  google-cloud-translate . Thanks

Comment: Isn't that what I answered!?

Comment: I think I've got what you written :)